# How to pass req.user from express-validator to next middleware

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I have an email validation going on with express-validator,
I want to pass req.user from express-validator to next middleware
I tried this:

```
body("email")
.custom((value, { req}) => {
    User.findOne({ email: value})
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("No account found with this email"); 
        } else {
          req.user = user; // this is undefined in next middleware
          return true;
        }
      })
      .catch(
        err => console.log(err);
      );
```

how can I can set `req.user = user`?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible. There is an issue in the express-validator repo https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/953

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can set a middleware that checks the user email like so:

set up your middleware

**validator.js**

```
const validator = value => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: value });
    if (user) {
      res.user = user;
      next();
    }
    return res.status(401).json({ data: 'No account found with this email' });
  } catch (error) {}
};

module.exports = validator;
```

include your middleware in the route you want it to work:

**user.js**

```
const validator = require('<path to your validator middleware>');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',validator(value),(req,res)=>{

 //DO SOMTHING

}
```

the middleware will check input `value` and validate it. hopefully this makes sense,
good luck!